# Why are event handlers being removed in this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand why event handlers need to be removed. I'm a beginner developer, and I searched all over for the answer but couldn't find the reason. 
I came across the code below and I see that the event handler is removed as soon as it is bound. Is it a good practice?

```
bindSubmitEvent: function() {
  var self = this;
  $('#submitBtn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).off('click', self.bindSubmitEvent);
    self.validateForm();

    if (self.options.valid_selection) {
      self.submitForm();
    } else {
      $('#submitRegistrationBtn').on('click', self.bindSubmitEvent);
      console.log("not valid");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It's a rather odd thing to be doing in this instance, but there are certain cases when removing event handlers is required. There's no 'best practice' here as it depends on the use case.

Comment: "as soon as it is bound" — No. That's as soon as it is **fired**

Comment: It appears that it is removing the submit binding in the case that the validation passes, so that the next submit will not validate again, which would be an infinite loop potentially with the `self.submitForm();`

Comment: _I'm trying to understand why event handlers need to be removed_ Where did you read that? Of course there are some cases where it's necessary to remove event handlers. However, it can't really be described as a "practice" at all.

Comment: Is the code really adding a handler for a different button than the one being clicked? One with a creepily similar name? That looks like a bug in waiting.

Comment: Removing event handlers *can* be good practice, but it is highly situational.  The main situation that come to mind was one I enountered on a page that had many inputs that used a datepicker.  The original logic initialized the datepicker on all the fields on page load, which caused a delay in the initial load of the page while all that initialization happened.  We then changed it so that the fields only initialized the datepicker when the user focused on it the first time, removing that focus event after it executed.  In that case, it removed the page load delay and made sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've shown does not work.
`this` inside the inner click handler is `#submitButton`, therefore trying to detach the `self.bindSubmitEvent` from it makes no sense, as that function was never attached to it.

Also `$('#submitRegistrationBtn').on('click', self.bindSubmitEvent)` will cause more trouble, as two events will be attached at the next click, and the second one will be called with `this` (and therefore `self` being the `#submitRegistrationBtn`. That will probably cause the whole code to fail (silently).

> Is it a good practice?

Non working code is not a good practice, no. Removing an event listener sometimes makes sense (e.g. if the form was submitted, you want the registration button to be disabled), in most cases however, it is way easier to just remove the button itself (as it serves no functionality without a listener attached).